# What are some good books in order to study for the 70-668 SharePoint exam?

Tags: 2010, certificate

Lectori salutem,

I'm planning on taking the Exam "70-668:
PRO: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Administrator" in the near future and was wondering what study material to use. What books do you recommend to study from?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have made this a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Practising exam papers will not be enough to prepare for 70 - 668 or 667.

You need to do a lot of practice and need real life experience of SharePoint administration.

You can go through this study guide,

[SharePoint 2010 70-668 Study Guide](http://blog.msih.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-70-668-study-guide.html)

or Microsoft's training course,

[Collection 10174B: Configuring and Administering Microsoft® SharePoint® 2010](https://www.microsoftelearning.com/eLearning/collection.aspx?guid=EFBCA18A-D7C1-4490-9CC0-E9D22A999D95)

If you still looking for a book,

[Professional SharePoint 2010 Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470533331)

I am a developer and planning for it too, but I am about to buy a good server and then practice on it for months before trying 668.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Muhammad. Do you know if the book "Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Administration: Real World Skills for MCITP Certification and Beyond" by James Pyles is any good?

Comment: Nope I didn't read this book yet, but it looks promising for SharePoint administrators who have good experience and would like to extend there knowledge (Its a personal opinion).